# How to convert this text (json lookalike) extracted from page to dataframe?

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

```
text <- "\n    var kml = '';\n    var PruebaTest = [\n        {\"nom\": \"MONTE GRANDE\", \"cate\": \"CO\", \"lat\": -7.22499, \"lon\": -79.15323, \"ico\": \"M\", \"cod\": \"100090\",\"cod_old\": \"000396\", \"estado\": \"DIFERIDO\"},\n{\"nom\": \"PUENTE  MAYGASBAMBA\", \"cate\": \"HLG\", \"lat\": -6.67411, \"lon\": -78.52437, \"ico\": \"H\", \"cod\": \"221110\",\"cod_old\": \"220307\", \"estado\": \"DIFERIDO\"},\n{\"nom\": \"QUEBRADA SHUGAR\", \"cate\": \"PLU\", \"lat\": -6.68778, \"lon\": -78.45694, \"ico\": \"M\", \"cod\": \"100113\",\"cod_old\": \"153108\", \"estado\": \"DIFERIDO\"},\n{\"nom\": \"CHUGUR\", \"cate\": \"PLU\", \"lat\": -6.66878, \"lon\": -78.738, \"ico\": \"M\", \"cod\": \"106077\",\"cod_old\": \"153208\", \"estado\": \"DIFERIDO\"},\n    ];\n"
```

I tried `jsonlite::fromJSON(text)` but this error happens:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       var kml = '';     var PruebaTes
                     (right here) ------^
```

The whole text you can get it from:

```
url <- "https://www.senamhi.gob.pe/mapas/mapa-estaciones-2/"

whole_text <- rvest::read_html(url) %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath = '//script[@type = "text/javascript"]') %>% 
  rvest::html_text()
```

I need to get a dataframe out of `text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(sub("\\}[^{]+$", "}]", sub("^[^[]+", "", whole_text)))

                             nom cate       lat       lon ico    cod cod_old   estado
1                   MONTE GRANDE   CO  -7.22499 -79.15323   M 100090  000396 DIFERIDO
2            PUENTE  MAYGASBAMBA  HLG  -6.67411 -78.52437   H 221110  220307 DIFERIDO
3                QUEBRADA SHUGAR  PLU  -6.68778 -78.45694   M 100113  153108 DIFERIDO
4                         CHUGUR  PLU  -6.66878 -78.73800   M 106077  153208 DIFERIDO
5                  LA CASCARILLA   CO  -5.67175 -78.89767   M 105062  000349 DIFERIDO
6                       CHONTALI   CO  -5.64389 -79.09000   M 105065  000250 DIFERIDO
7                          CACAO  HLM  -5.88370 -78.96250   H 220405  220405 DIFERIDO
8                       EL LIMON   CO  -5.91778 -79.31722   M 105057  000241 DIFERIDO
9                HACIENDA PUCARA  PLU  -6.04167 -79.13389   M 106065  153107 DIFERIDO
10                      SALLIQUE   CO  -5.65886 -79.31264   M 105053  002129 DIFERIDO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a chunk of raw javascript code. That's not quite the same thing as JSON data. You can't have blank elements in arrays in JSON but you can have them on a javascript literal. You'd have to mangle the code into a proper shape. Assuming you're trying to extract the data in `PruebaTest` you can remove all the `var` stuff before that and drop the extra comma with a `gsub`

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub(".*?var PruebaTest =(.*?),\\s+(\\]);","\\1\\2", text))
```

Which gives

```
                  nom cate      lat       lon ico    cod cod_old   estado
1        MONTE GRANDE   CO -7.22499 -79.15323   M 100090  000396 DIFERIDO
2 PUENTE  MAYGASBAMBA  HLG -6.67411 -78.52437   H 221110  220307 DIFERIDO
3     QUEBRADA SHUGAR  PLU -6.68778 -78.45694   M 100113  153108 DIFERIDO
4              CHUGUR  PLU -6.66878 -78.73800   M 106077  153208 DIFERIDO
```

But note this is not a general solution. You need to carefully understand the javascript code and turn it into a proper JSON structure. This should be different for every javascript code chunk.

Comment: Do you know why using `stringr::str_replace` does not work?

Comment: I added the whole text because this: `jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub(".*?var PruebaTest =(.*?),\\s+(\\]);","\\1\\2", text))` does not work on it. Please, is there a way around it?